# StackCrunch - A platform to share your development Experiences

Tags: app, website, stackoverflow

[image: StackCunch - Share your dev stories!]

#### About:

A place where you can share your development experiences & learn from stories rooted in real-world practical solutions.

StackExchange communities are undoubtedly the best places to learn to code while creating amazing products & help others do the same by sharing solutions to problems you faced.

As a result, these communities become an integral part of our development journey.
StackCrunch is a platform where you can log & share that experience with the rest of the world.

Your followers can get regular updates & learn from your experience while you get to do the same from others.

You read more about why I built this platform [here](https://stackcrunch.io/post/StackCrunch-Crowdsourcing-Practical-Solutions-rJeRqu5y5f).

Why not an SE community newsletter subscription?
Community Newsletters contain latest questions with some personalization according to your preferred tags & activity.
StackCrunch is a little different in regards to have more context and allowing the user to make a little more elaborate description of his experience.

Here is a screenshot of the editor:

[image: StackCrunch Editor]

It supports a variety of options & embeds like images, videos(youtube, vimeo, etc.), code snippets (codesandbox, jsfiddle & codepen) & ofcourse stackexchange community post embeds.

#### Download / Install:

To dive right in visit - https://stackcrunch.io

#### Contact:

If you have some feedback, please get in touch below or via twitter - https://twitter.com/stackcrunchio